# How to set MessageVersion in binding in app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a binding in my app.config file like so:

```
 <bindings>    
  <basicHttpBinding>        
    <binding name="WebapiBindingWithCred" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>          
      </security>        
    </binding>   
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

When I use it, I get `Unrecognized message version' error as a response. I've read I should set my MessageVersion to Soap11, but I can't find the tag to do so anywhere. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following tag in your binding:

```
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
```

However, you need to use a custom binding though, rather than the basicHttpBinding:

```
 <customBinding>  
    <binding name="HttpBinding" >  
        <textMessageEncoding   
            messageVersion="Soap11"/>  
        <httpTransport />  
    </binding>  
 </customBinding>
```

Comment: `The element binding has invalid child element textMessageEncoding` is what I get.

Comment: It should be inside a `<customBinding>`.

Comment: With the custom binding element, I cannot set the security mode tag, so I'm just trading one problem for another.

Comment: Thank you Dan, this helped me a lot.